# Domain name reserved: it doesn't show in any registry, but it is not available. How to get it?

Tags: domain, domain-name, registrar

I am trying to register a .com domain name for a NGO (non profit).

They already own, let's say, **example**.org and I'd like to register **example**.com on their behalf.   There's nothing special about that name, except to friends of that nonprofit.

When I look it up in whois, I get a message saying the domain name is unknown in the registry.

But when I go to buy it, several registrars say it's taken, and at least one offered to track down the owner for a hefty fee.

A few days ago the domain (formerly owned by a squatter) was in its redemption period, and has now expired.

ICANN says there's a way for registrars to reserve domains (like the real example.com), and I've heard some registrars abuse this.

What is this? How can I get register this domain without paying an arm and a leg?

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/when-can-i-register-an-expired-domain-name-572